# Cannot add ArcGIS ModelBuilder output to table of contents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst, inverse-distance-weighted

I've made a model that creates some points with Z value and a buffer, which I then do a 3D analyst IDW on, and a Cut Fill analysis.

The model input is a line along with af DEM/Raster, and some names for the output files. However I would like to show the IDW output as a layer that will be opened in the Table Of Contents and displayed as well as the CutFill, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

Answer: Adding a *Make Raster Layer* after the *IDW* output seems to do the trick as well.

[Link for the toolbox with the model in it](https://ufile.io/7b2dw)

[image]

Comment: You say "...would like to show the IDW output in the layers...", layers of what?

Comment: @Hornbydd Perhaps a poor phrasing, what I mean is, the Output should be added to the table of contents and shown in the data view, so I can see the result of the IDW which is used afterwards for the cut fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the help file under the page title of [Display model data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/displaying-model-data.htm), the note explains how to make it add to table of contents.

Quoting from ESRI help file:

> Add To Display has no effect outside ModelBuilder. When running a
>   model tool from its dialog box or the Python window, the Add To
>   Display setting will not be honored. To add model data variables to
>   the display when running the model from its dialog box or the Python
>   window, make the data variable a model parameter, then enable the Add
>   results of geoprocessing operations to the display option from the
>   Standard toolbar: Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options > Add results
>   of geoprocessing operations to the display.

Comment: Adding a _Make Raster Layer_ after the_IDW_ output seems to do the trick as well.